# DQNにおいて、MacBook ProとGoogle ColabのGPUを使用したときの学習に差が生じる問題について

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, ニューラルネットワーク

python tensorflow  Keras-rl使用して、DQNをCNNモデルを使用して学習させています。
そこで、自身のMacBook Proを使用して学習させたときと、GoogleColabのGPUを使用して学習させたときに、
結果に天と地ほどの差が生まれてました。

学習時間が大きく変わることは承知していますが、MacBookではあまりいい結果が出ないのに対し、Colabではいい結果が出ました。
何回繰り返しても、同様の結果が出てしまいます。

また、いい結果の出ているモデルを使用して、MacBookとColabにおいて動かした結果、
MacBookでは下手でしたが、Colabではちゃんと上手なプレイをしていました。

これは、マシンの性能に差があるために、ニューラルネットワークがうまく機能していないなど、
そういったことが起きているのでしょうか？